# Why can't I access properties of an anonymous type returned from a function via the dynamic keyword?

Tags: c#, dynamic, anonymous-types

I have a function that returns an anonymous type like so (simplified for illustrative purposes)...

```
public object GetPropertyInfo()
{
    return new {
        PropertyName = "Foo",
        Value = "Laa"
    };
}
```

When I do this...

```
dynamic pi = GetPropertyInfo();
Console.WriteLine(pi);
```

It outputs this (the same as if I did '?pi' in the immediate window)...

```
{ PropertyName = "A", Value = 44 }
    PropertyName: "A"
    Value: 44
```

But if I try doing this...

```
   string propertyName = pi.PropertyName;
```

...it compiles but throws a runtime exception saying

> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'PropertyName'

What gives? What am I missing here?

Comment: What does `GetPropertyInfo()` actually return? What's the implementation? That error you're getting indicates it's not just an anonymous object, otherwise you wouldn't get that error. If `pi` _was_ dynamic, then that line would not even produce that error, `propertyName` would also be dynamic.

Comment: @MarqueIV: Are they two predefined properties? You don't need dynamic at all unless it has dynamic properties.

Comment: The dynamic was because I was trying to access properties of an anonymous type, cast through the return type of `object`.  Object doesn't have PropertyType or Value, hence the use of Dynamic.  I think the issue is the internal restriction, but I'm still curious how VS's output window gets around that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that [anonymous types are internal](http://heartysoft.com/ashic/blog/2010/05/anonymous-types-c-sharp-4-dynamic/), which means that you can't access their properties with `dynamic` property accessors from projects other than the one they were created in. The dynamic binding treats them as the closest public inherited type it knows about--`object`.

To fix this, you can declare a public type to represent the values you're expecting to find in your anonymous type. This is probably a good idea anyway, since you're clearly expecting to consume the returned properties in other parts of your code. Using a declared type also enables you to maintain type-safety, avoiding the need for `dynamic` entirely.

If you absolutely *must* use `dynamic`s here, the next best option is probably to change your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file to make internal properties accessible to the project you're trying to access them from:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("MyOtherProject")]
```

Comment: But if they are internal as you say, then why does the console know about them?  Even doing '?pi' in the immediate window shows PropertyName and Value. If it can, why can't my code?  That said, yeah, I've been trying to avoid creating an extra type just for this, but I think I'll have to go that route.

Comment: Whether it was internal or not shouldn't matter, unless the dynamic object was being returned from a function of a different assembly. But the question doesn't indicate anything about the source of the objects. For all we know, everything is within the same assembly.

Comment: @MarqueIV: The `ToString()` function on anonymous types is auto-implemented to output the values of all their properties. It's not the console that understands how to find their properties--it's their internal code that knows to output those values when the public `ToString()` method is called.

Comment: @JeffMercado: Correct. I'm making a logical leap to assume that this is being accessed across assembly boundaries.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but ToString() actually only returns "{ PropertyName = A, Value = 44 }" which doesn't have the extra two additional lines showing in the output window: those lines having the anonymous property name (which for the first *is* 'PropertyName' and the second is 'Value'), then a colon, then the value of those properties.  That's why I'm confused.  It does seem to have access to the anonymous type outside of ToString.

Comment: @MarqueIV: Good point. They must be doing some extra magic for the immediate window. I know that debug watches and such will still allow you to see private properties and fields--it's likely that's related. By the way, have you considered using an existing type like `KeyValuePair<string, object>` as your return type? That might help you avoid creating a special type, and Key/Value seems pretty close to what you're going for here.

Comment: I thought about that, but I'd rather create a concrete class that handles it for me.  That's really the way I should be going.  Still, I'm marking this as the answer because I think in the end you're right... it was Internal that was biting me.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

According to your edit. Apparently **you are not required dynamic at all** as there are no dynamic properties. Just create a concrete type with your predefined properties. It's better to avoid dynamic when possible anyway.

**Old Answer**

You need to use an `ExpandoObject`. Reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

In fact, `GetPropertyInfo()` should return an `ExpandoObject`.

```
    dynamic foo = this.GetPropertyInfo();
    string i = foo.MyPropertyName;

    private ExpandoObject GetPropertyInfo()
    {
        dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
        obj.PropertyName = "MyPropertyName";
        obj.PropertyType = "MyPropertyType";

        return obj;
    }
```

> The ExpandoObject class enables you to add and delete members of its
>   instances at run time and also to set and get values of these members.
>   This class supports dynamic binding, which enables you to use standard
>   syntax like sampleObject.sampleMember instead of more complex syntax
>   like sampleObject.GetAttribute("sampleMember").

Comment: It doesn't _need_ to be an expando object... we don't even know what the actual use cases are here. To suggest that is very misleading.

Comment: I was just writing something saying exactly that.  It will always be two properties; PropertyName and Value.  I think just creating a concrete type will solve my issue, but I'm still curious about the anonymous type/internal thing, which makes sense, but still doesn't explain how the output/immediate window know more than the simple value of ToString.

Comment: @JeffMercado: I think you are correct as per the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use `System.Reflection`

```
object D = GetPropertyInfo(); 
Type t = D.GetType(); // get object's type
PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperty("PropertyName"); // look up for the property:
object P = p.GetValue(D, null); // get the value
```

[Fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/apz5mk)